# CakePHP3 REST API Triggers only index method

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to build RESTful API using CakePHP3. The problem is no matter what type of HTTP request I'm sending to, it always launches the index method.

My routes.php config:

```
/**
 * REST Routes
 */
Router::scope('/articles', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->resources('Articles');
});

Router::scope('/users', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->resources('Users');
});

Router::scope('/categories', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->resources('Categories');
});
```

The example controller looks like this:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->cors($this->request)
        ->allowOrigin(['*'])
        ->allowMethods(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
        ->build();
}
public function index()
{
    echo 'index';
}

public function view($id = null)
{
    echo "view:".$id;
}

public function add()
{
    echo 'add';
}
```

I'm using Postman to send HTTP requests. The response I get from every type of request is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a closer look at the docs again, that's not how you would connect ressource routes. They way you are doing it, ie passing additional scopes with the same name as the ressource, would create routes like

```
/users/users
```

(check `bin/cake routes` for a list of all connected routes), ie your visit to

```
/users
```

matches a different route, probably a fallback one.

You should connect your routes to the `/` scope instead (assuming that the `/api/` part in your screenshot is part of the folder structure), like:

```php
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->resources('Articles');
    $routes->resources('Users');
    $routes->resources('Categories');
});
```

That will create routes in the form of

```
/users (GET)
/users (POST)
/users/:id (GET)
etc...
```

See also

- **[Cookboook > Routing > Creating RESTful Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#resource-routes)**
- **[Cookboook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > Routes Shell](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/routes-shell.html)**

Comment: That fixed everything. Thanks a lot :)